# How to use NSCalendarDayChanged - swift

Tags: swift

The following code isn't working (isn't activating calendarDayDidChange) when the date changes:

```
// Define identifier
let notificationName = Notification.Name("NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged")

// Register to receive notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(calendarDayDidChange(notification:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

The method header is

```
func calendarDayDidChange(notification : NSNotification)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSCalendarDayChanged is already of type NSNotification.Name so you don't need to cast it.

```
let notificationName: Notification.Name = .NSCalendarDayChanged
```

or

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged
```